# secure attribute on cookies created in javascript

Tags: security, ssl, cookies, https

When cookies are created purely client-side in javascript by setting document.cookie(), what effect does the "secure" attribute have on them?

In particular:

- are client-created cookies sent to the server in the "Cookie:" header of subsequent requests?
- can client-created be modified by subsequent Set-Cookie headers from the server?
- in the case of the previous two questions, assuming the answer is yes, does the secure attribute prevent this if the connection with the server isn't HTTPS?
- if a page *not* loaded over HTTPS contains javascript that tries to create cookies with the secure attribute, will the cookies even be allowed to be created?
- do the major browsers handle all this consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, JavaScript-set cookies (set via document.cookie=) are sent to the server in the Cookie request header.
2. Yes, client-set cookies can be overwritten by server-delivered Set-Cookie headers.
3. Yes, it should.
4. It should not.
5. As far as I know, yes, but it should be easy to test.